# How to use System Font with an Attributed String?

Tags: swift, fonts, nsattributedstring, nsmutableattributedstring, swift2

```
let attributedText: NSMutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: text, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "San Francisco", size: 14.0)!])
```

Using the code above, when I run my app it crashes because it cannot find the "San Francisco" font. But isn't that the system font for iOS 9? How can I use the system font in an attributed string?

I am using Swift 2.2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can construct a font using the system constructors:

```
var foo = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(fontSize: CGFloat)
```

Comment: i just downloaded the SF font from apples website and it looks like its working

Comment: But this actually answers your question. In  iOS8 and earlier the system font is *not* San Francisco, rather Helvetica Neue Light. Depends on your goal.

Comment: true. My app only supports ios8 on so i might just add an if statement. But I'll see what your code does!

Comment: yup your code works much better then what I was thinking of doing! Thanks!